# Getting an graphwidth-error using the r function forestplot

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I'm trying to make a forestplot by using the package forestplot but I always get the following error:

`Error in Ops.unit(graphwidth, "auto") : operator '==' not meaningful for units`

This is my code:

```
forestplot(row_names, coef, low, high, new_page=T, xticks=c(0,0.5,1, 1.5,2, 2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5), boxsize=0.4, zero=1, cex=1.65, cex.axis=1.5, lwd.zero=3, lwd.ci=3, clip=c(0,5), graphwidth = unit(x = 10, units = "inches"),
       fn.ci_norm=list(fpDrawNormalCI, fpDrawNormalCI, fpDrawDiamondCI, fpDrawNormalCI, fpDrawDiamondCI,fpDrawNormalCI, fpDrawDiamondCI,fpDrawNormalCI, fpDrawDiamondCI,fpDrawNormalCI, fpDrawDiamondCI,fpDrawNormalCI, fpDrawDiamondCI,fpDrawNormalCI, fpDrawDiamondCI,fpDrawNormalCI, fpDrawDiamondCI, fpDrawNormalCI, fpDrawDiamondCI, fpDrawNormalCI))
```

I created the same plot a couple of month ago and it worked fine. At that time the forestplot function was implemented in the Gmisc-package. Now it is an own package and it seems that something changed. I'm defining the graphwidth-parameter correctly, as far as I know . Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Best,
Tobi

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, fixed and on CRAN.